# how to edit author details for gitg?

Tags: git

I just recently installed gitg and whenever I tried to make a commit, I encountered an error of missing author details. However, I am unable to change `author details` as no editing window pops up after I clicked on the the `author details` tab...

[image]

Comment: Hi. I have noticed the same problem. I think this is a bug. I reported it on GNOME Bugzilla : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the error you need to set your user name and email address.
There are two main contexts where you will likely want to set this

1. Specific to your user account i.e. `~/.gitconfig`
   This setting will apply to any git project belonging to your user account
2. On a project specific basis i.e. in `<your_git_project>/.git/config`
   This setting will be used by that particular project - if for some reason you want a particular project to attach a  different username and email  address to your commits.
3. You also can set config options at a system wide level - but I'm not going to cover that

to set an email address at a user level

- `git config --global user.name "John Doe"`
- `git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

to set an email address at a project level.

- `cd` in to the root of the git repo
- `git config user.name "John Doe"`
- `git config user.email johndoe@example.com`

Answer (score 2):

You can put the entry in config file of your repository. see the path like ***.git/config***

- git config --global user.name "Display Name"
- git config --global user.email "emailid@example.com"

For more detail:

Type ***git config*** to see output like below:

```
--global              use global config file

--system              use system config file

--local               use repository config file
```